# How to make a round mask over a image

Tags: javascript, css, mask

This is my take using css only, but the image is not centred, and also the image get bigger not the mask

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shbnts90/2/)

I want to achieve the same affect in here

http://jackietrananh.com/portfolio.php

He is using an image http://jackietrananh.com/img/sprite-s82d3b02845.png but how this can happen with pure css or js?

and without

```
clip-path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would accomplish this as follows:
 HTML:

```
<div class="round">
   <img src="http://www.somebodymarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Stock-Dock-House.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.round{
  width:10%;
  padding-top:10%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  min-width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  transition: 1s ease;
}
img:hover{
  height:110%;
}
```

Example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/mJeYye?editors=110)

Answer (score 3):

```
.avatar-frame{border: 2px solid #c7b89e;}
.avatar-frame,.avatar-frame img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px; /* Saf3+, Chrome */
    border-radius: 30px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */
    /*-moz-border-radius: 30px;  Disabled for FF1+ */
    }
```

more here
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 1):

With css you can set it as a `background` and positioning it to center:

```
background: url("http://media.trb.com/media/photo/2011-11/241153480-30235112.jpg") no-repeat center center;
```

Here's a demo:http://jsfiddle.net/shbnts90/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shbnts90/4/)

```
.circle {  
margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
-moz-border-radius:50%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%;
border-radius:50%;
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
.circle>img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   max-height:100%;
}
.circle:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the CSS for the image as a 50% border radius, it will create what is effectively a full circle mask around an image.

```
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Note, some of the original links in this original question expired, so I'm guessing a little about the intent here based on the dialog.